# How to create details table in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have completed html table that make it looks like a form. But I want to move to javascript that can create a table that have input and list options element and remove table element depend on user selectedindexchanged.
I was looking at example of javascript and it seems too long than creating html table. Can anyone give me a example or a reference link that almost like this and it easier and quicker to codes?

Here is small example of html that I want javascript to create. I have alot more rows but I am keeping this small.

```
    <div id= "WindowForm" align="center"><center><b>Window Information</b>
<table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
          <td width="100%" valign="top" class="headerborder"><b>
            Data Entry (Please fill in):</b></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="356">
          <tr>
          <td width="30%" ><b>Project</b></td><td width="67%" >
            <input type="text" name="Project" size="48"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="30%"><b>Affiliate</b></td>
            <td width="67%"><b><select size="1" name="Affiliate">
            <option selected value="LAW Proper">Dow Proper</option>
            <option value="Sadara BSD">Sadara BSD</option>
            <option value="Sadara MOM">Sadara MOM</option>
            <option value="Sadara SVC">Sadara SVC</option>
            <option value="Amsty">Amsty</option>
            <option value="Styro">Styro</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select></b></td>
          </tr>
    </table>
    </center>
    </div>
```

Comment: My Advise is use AngularJS or any other template library

Comment: Have you considered using a grid?